# dnsmasq stops after auto-starting after OS upgrade

Tags: debian, dnsmasq

I have upgraded my rPi2 from Wheezy to Jessie... it boots and seems OK, except dnsmasq fails after boot with:

```
sudo service dnsmasq status
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
           └─50-dnsmasq-$named.conf, 50-insserv.conf-$named.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2017-06-07 19:55:39 AEST; 24min ago
  Process: 1526 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-stop-resolvconf (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 626 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 558 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 634 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[558]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: started, version 2.72 cachesize 150
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP con...detect
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: using nameserver 180.181.127.4#53
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: using nameserver 180.181.127.3#53
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: using local addresses only for domain localnet.beta.net
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: no servers found in /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf, will retry
Jun 07 19:52:22 rpiserver dnsmasq[634]: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
Jun 07 19:54:09 rpiserver systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service start-post operation timed out. Stopping.
Jun 07 19:55:39 rpiserver systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service stopping timed out. Terminating.
Jun 07 19:55:39 rpiserver systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jun 07 19:55:39 rpiserver systemd[1]: Unit dnsmasq.service entered failed state.
```

I can start dnsmasq with sudo dnsmasq and it works.
(Bacground: I am using the isc-DHCP service; and later required a DNS proxy, when I installed dnsmasq.)

Any ideas on where to look?

The config is:

```
grep -E -v '(^$)|(^#)' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
domain-needed
bogus-priv
local=/localnet.beta.net/
server=180.181.12.3
server=180.181.12.4
interface=eth0
listen-address=127.0.0.1
no-dhcp-interface=
expand-hosts
domain=alpha.org
```

Comment: Please share the output of `systemctl cat dnsmasq.service`.

Comment: Appreciate the reply... however, have since, out of frustration and the idea of a better solution -- installed bind9.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies... this question can be removed... as I no longer run dnsmasq.
I have, out of frustration and the idea of a better solution, installed bind9. Together with isc-dhcp it now has greater functionality than dnsmasq could offer... and it is working :)
Thanks.